# Prove if $a_n>c>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}$ convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_n-c}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to prove the following claim:

If for any $n$, $a_n>c>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_n}$ convergent, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_n-c}$ is convergent.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{a_n-c}=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**:
$$
\frac{1}{a_n - c} = \frac{1}{1 - \frac{c}{a_n}} \cdot \frac{1}{a_n}
$$
and for large enough $n$, $\frac{c}{a_n} < \frac{1}{2}$.